# MongoDB, Mongoose - Slow query when fetching 10k+ documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database with 10-12k documents in a collection and I'm experiencing really slow queries when attempting to fetch all documents, like this:

```
Sales.find()
    .where('author').equals(author)
    .where('date').gt(startDate.unix()).lt(endDate.unix())
    .exec(function(err, results) {
        callback();
    });
```

This query fetches around 10.5k documents and it takes 1000-1300ms to execute. I tried removing the "where" conditions - it only makes it slower (more documents fetched?).

Does the problem come from Mongoose, MongoDB, JavaScript or Node? I used to run PHP/MySQL database and it was 10-20 times faster in similar conditions, like fetching 10k+ rows of data. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

Sales schema:

```
var salesSchema = new Schema({
    author: String,
    kind: String,
    productID: String,
    description: String,
    date: String,
    amount: String,
    transactionID: {
        type: String,
        unique : true
    }
});
```

Query result from the RoboMongo desktop client:

```
db.getCollection('sales').find({}).explain()

executionTimeMillis: 46
nReturned: 10359
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the schema definition of the `Sales` model, any indexes on the underlying collection, output from the [**`.explain()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) query plan for the mongo shell `db.collection.find()` method with the sample query?

Comment: Yes, I will do that, thanks!

Comment: I can see `date` is a String but your mongoose `Sales.find()` method is doing a date range query based on a unix timestamp field which is an integer, also it looks like you don't have any indexes defined on the `date` field so there might be a possibility that mongodb is doing a full collection scan. Can you also add the output from `db.getCollection('sales').find({author: author, date {gt: startDate, lt: endDate }}).explain()`?

Comment: Something is wrong I think. "db.getCollection('sales').find({author: 'nickys', date: {gt: '1325336400', lt: '1420030800' }}).explain()" doesn't return any results. I tried removing the quotes from the timestamps, but it didn't help. It works if I remove the entire date condition. Forgive me, I'm new to Mongo :)

Comment: Are you flexible enough to change the schema design? Was going to suggest that it might help with the query performance if you can convert the date field with the 'string' timestamp to a proper ISODate, then create an index on that field.

Comment: Yes, I can change the format of the date field. About making it an index - you mean a unique field? That will be a problem, because there will be duplicates once the database gets large enough.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a unique index, you could create it as a [**Single Field Index**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/) on the `date` field or as a [**Compound Index**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) on the `author` and `date` fields since your find query uses both fields.

Comment: I will read more about those indexes and update the post when I run the tests again. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92185/discussion-between-chridam-and-nikolay-dyankov).

Comment: doing range queries on a string is always expensive, especially if you don't have an index. You should consider making the date field either `Date` (in which case you'd save date objects) or `Number` (in which case you'd save them as a unix timestamp) and add an index

Comment: I agree @kio, but in my case significant overhead was caused by Mongoose, not MongoDB. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

The problem came from Mongoose. By default, find() will return documents as Mongoose Documents, which costs a lot. By adding lean() to the query, documents are returned as plain JavaScript objects and for this case of 10k+ returned documents, the query time got **reduced 3-5 times**.

```
Sales.find()
    .where('author').equals(author)
    .where('date').gt(startDate.unix()).lt(endDate.unix())
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, results) {
        callback();
    });
```

Read more here:
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/high-performance-find-query-using-lean-in-mongoose-2/

Comment: Thanks you saved my day!

Comment: What if you have over 100k+ and already set lean() but it's still taking a long time?

Comment: works with us from 33000ms to 5000ms for 70k documents

Comment: Great! I googled so many times but this is surely the correct answer.
It cuts down 3.0min to 2.6s for simple quering. Thanks a lot